# Fullcalendar, backbone.js, Cannot edit event

Tags: django, backbone.js, fullcalendar, tastypie

So, I think I am in over my head here. I am trying to get fullcalendar to work with backbone and django. I am still learning all of this but I can now make new events and save them via django-tastypie, and they do show up in the calendar, wohoo! However, I can not edit or drag them. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'isNew' of undefined line 96, is what I get when events are clicked and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'save' of undefined line 78. I have done my best to figure this out, but no success. Why is this.model.isnew() undefined in render and the same for save? I do not fully understand all of this so I have probably made some stupid mistake somewhere or misunderstood how everything works. I would be grateful if anyone could give me a hint.

I added `console.log(fcEvent);` to `eventClick`, and when I inspect it, it says start and end dates are invalid. Does anyone know what that means? If I inspect the same object just after it was added with `addOne`, the dates are valid. I am also using https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie if that matters.

edit: Tried this to make sure events.fetch() succeeded, this resulted in no events in the calendar whatsoever. Does that mean that events.fetch() never succeeds? I can see "GET /api/event/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6079 in the log.
alternative fetch:

```
events.fetch({
   success: function(){
   new EventsView({el: $("#calendar"), collection: events}).render();
    }});
```

Original program:

```
$(function(){
var Event = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Event,
    url: '/api/event/'

}); 

var EventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this); 

        this.collection.bind('reset', this.addAll);
        this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne);
        this.collection.bind('change', this.change);            
        this.collection.bind('destroy', this.destroy);

        this.eventView = new EventView();  

    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,basicDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            ignoreTimezone: false,
    disableResizing:false,               
            select: this.select,
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

            eventClick: this.eventClick,
            eventDrop: this.eventDropOrResize,        
            eventResize: this.eventDropOrResize,
    events: 'events'

        });
    },
    addAll: function() {
        this.$el.fullCalendar('addEventSource', this.collection.toJSON());
    },
    addOne: function(event) {
        this.$el.fullCalendar('renderEvent', event.toJSON(), true);

    },        
    select: function(start, end, allDay) { 
        var eventView = new EventView();
    console.log('select');
    eventView.collection = this.collection;
        eventView.model = new Event({start: start, end: end, allDay: allDay});
        eventView.render();            
    },
    eventClick: function(fcEvent) {
    console.log('click');
this.eventView.collection = this.collection;
this.eventView.model = this.collection.at(fcEvent.id);
console.log(fcEvent);
        this.eventView.render();
    },
    change: function(event) {
        // Look up the underlying event in the calendar and update its details from the model
        var fcEvent = this.$el.fullCalendar('clientEvents', event.get('id'))[0];
        fcEvent.title = event.get('title');
        fcEvent.color = event.get('color');
console.log('change');
        this.$el.fullCalendar('updateEvent', fcEvent); 

    },
    eventDropOrResize: function(fcEvent) {
    console.log(fcEvent);
        // Lookup the model that has the ID of the event and update its attributes
        this.eventView.collection.at(fcEvent.id).save({start: fcEvent.start, end: fcEvent.end});            
    },
    destroy: function(event) {
        this.$el.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);         
    }        
});

var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: $('#eventDialog'),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this); 


    },
    render: function() {

    var buttons = {'Ok': this.save};
        if (!this.model.isNew()) {
            _.extend(buttons, {'Delete': this.destroy});
        }
        _.extend(buttons, {'Cancel': this.close});            

        this.$el.dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: (this.model.isNew() ? 'New' : 'Edit') + ' Event',
            buttons: buttons,
            open: this.open
        });

        return this;
    },        
    open: function() {
        this.$('#title').val(this.model.get('title'));
        this.$('#color').val(this.model.get('color'));

    },        
    save: function() {
        this.model.set({'title': this.$('#title').val(), 'color': this.$('#color').val(),});
    console.log('save');
        if (this.model.isNew()) {
            this.collection.create(this.model, {success: this.close,wait: true });
        } else {
            this.model.save({}, {success: this.close});
        }

    },
    close: function() {
        this.$el.dialog('close');
    },
    destroy: function() {
        this.model.destroy({success: this.close});
    }        
});

var events = new Events();
new EventsView({el: $("#calendar"), collection: events}).render();
events.fetch();

});
```

Comment: Regarding this line `var events = new Events();
new EventsView({el: $("#calendar"), collection: events}).render();
events.fetch();`. Have you tried doing the `fetch()` before creating the `new EventsView({})`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it made no difference, same undefined error.

Comment: Also tried running `events.fetch({async: false});` but that made no difference either.

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug and see what's coming back when you do a `fetch()`? Is it coming back with data at all?

Comment: This is my first encounter with javascript ever, so I am slowly figuring all this out. But, yes, there is data coming back. The only strange thing I can see is that start and enddates are invalid if i inspect them in `eventClick`, that is, after some event has been clicked, but they are valid if inspected just after the events has been added by `addOne`. I am just about ready to give up, maybe I should have started with printing hello world instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working except for events not actually disappearing from the calendar, even though they are deleted in the database. I dont know if this is the correct way to do this, probably not, but it worked. Model was undefined in EventView so I had to get the model from the collection and pass it on to EventView.

```
 eventClick: function(fcEvent) {
    console.log(fcEvent.id);

    this.mymodel = this.collection.where({'id':fcEvent.id})[0];
this.eventView = new EventView({collection: this.collection, model: this.mymodel})
this.eventView.render();
    },
    change: function(event) {
        // Look up the underlying event in the calendar and update its details from the model
        var fcEvent = this.$el.fullCalendar('clientEvents', event.get('id'))[0];
        fcEvent.title = event.get('title');
        fcEvent.color = event.get('color');
console.log('change');
        this.$el.fullCalendar('updateEvent', fcEvent); 

    },
    eventDropOrResize: function(fcEvent) {
    console.log(fcEvent);
        // Lookup the model that has the ID of the event and update its attributes
        this.collection.where({'id':fcEvent.id})[0].save({start: fcEvent.start, end: fcEvent.end});            
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. The issue comes down to an `undefined` Model.

On this line.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) { 
    var eventView = new EventView();
    eventView.collection = this.collection;
    eventView.model = new Event({start: start, end: end, allDay: allDay});
    eventView.render();            
},...
```

Change it to. I have a feeling that your `Model` is not being instantiated properly.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) { 
    var eventView = new EventView({
        collection: this.collection,
        model: new Event({start: start, end: end, allDay: allDay})  
    });
    eventView.render();            
},
```

Another issue is, you're instantiating the `EventsView` and passing in the collection and models before the `fetch` call.

```
var events = new Events();
$.when(events.fetch()).then(function() {
    // Create the Events view when the Events asynchronous operation completes.
    new EventsView({el: $("#calendar"), collection: events}).render();
});
```

Edit: here's a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ibonuh/1/) for additional changes.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the result was exactly the same. Cannot call method 'isNew' of undefined. I forgot to mention that I read somewhere that fetch() is async and can cause timing issues, so I have tried everything I could think of with that to but it did not change anything. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Your last suggestion gets no events in the calendar at all. It seems events.fetch() somehow does not work fully. The strange thing is that events actually pop up in the calendar if I do it like I originally did. This is strange.

Comment: Check out the JSBin link I added. I made some changes.

Comment: I tried your code and it results in no events in the calendar at all. The events only show up if I run fetch separately, but then the undefined problem is still there.